# $B$ is a subset of some $s(n)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume that $s$ is a function with domain $\omega$ such that $s(n) \subseteq s(n^+)$ for each $n \in \omega$. Assume that $B \subseteq \bigcup_{n\in\omega}s(n)$ such that for every infinite subset $B'$ of $B$ there is some $n$ for which $B'\cap s(n)$ is infinite.
Then $B$ is subset of some $s(n)$.

A  suggestion please or any  idea to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Brian M. Scott I already corrected the error.

Comment: You missed one $S$, but I went ahead and fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Suppose that $B$ is not a subset of any $s(n)$. Then for each $n\in\omega$ there is an $x_n\in B\setminus s(n)$. Moreover, you can choose the $x_n$ recursively so that $x_n\notin\{x_k:k<n\}$ for each $n\in\omega$.

Let $B'=\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$, and show that $B'$ is infinite, but $B'\cap s(n)$ is finite for each $n\in\omega$. You’ll need to use the hypothesis that $s(n)\subseteq s(n^+)$ for each $n\in\omega$.